# AngularJS, Restangular, how to patch edited retrieve data in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, restangular

I'm running into a problematic situation using angularJS.

My goal is to get data from a particular user and put this in my form model `$scope.user`.

After the user has edited the data, I would like them to be able to save their modification(s).

I want to `PATCH` only modified data (and not the empty fields for example) but the object contains everything my `GET` returned.

This is how I get my data and bind it to my model:

```
var student = Restangular.one('users', AuthHandler.authentication.userId);
student.get().then(function(result) {
  $scope.student = result;
});
```

In my form I can easily use ng-model like so:

```
<textarea name="about" class=" form-control" ng-model="student.about"></textarea>
```

And this is my update function

```
$scope.update = function() {
  data = Restangular.stripRestangular($scope.student) // Remove restangular method from object
  student.patch(data);
}
```

At this point, my problem is that the object data contains different fields not required for my patch.

The question is, should I bind each required data element, one by one, to a different model and then patch those data elements, or is my approach not suitable for what I'm trying to do?